# for camunda ,Claim a task will change act_hi_taskinst?

Tags: bpmn, camunda

For camunda bpm platform,

I guess claim a task will set owner in `act_hi_taskinst` to a value, but when we `getTaskService().claim`, we found nothing changed in `act_hi_taskinst`.

So we want to know if claim a task will set owner in `act_hi_taskinst`, and if so, will debug the code, if not, so will change what table data?
So if we know this, we will get data in table to determine if should ask a user to claim or not.

Thank you in advance.